# Silence exceptions coming from WCF discovery behavior

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ws-discovery

I've enabled support for managed discovery into my WCF services and I noticed that if the discovery server (or a discovery server) is unavailable then the service trying to announce its presence to the network will fail to start (complaining that the discovery server can't be contacted).

That does not seem right to me. Is there any way to avoid that?

I'm doing something like this

```
 var discoveryBehavior = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
 discoveryBehavior.AnnouncementEndpoints.Add(new AnnouncementEndpoint(DiscoveryVersion.WSDiscovery11, netTcpBinding, address));
 host.Description.Behaviors.Add(discoveryBehavior);
```